# Formatting real number in php (DB Postgres)

Tags: php, postgresql

i have a real number in my db postgres which is saving as follows:

1.23451e+006

I'm using a db postgres, so, I tried to use the function number format as follows:

```
$value=number_format($value, 2, ',', '.');
```

But I'm having an insertion error because the comma makes the decimals look like other elements to insert

I want the format of the numbers to look like: 9.999,99 for example

Comment: The format you want is really the responsibility of the presentation layer, most likely in this case PHP.  You should not be inserting such data into your Postgres table.  Instead, just insert the exponential data and then deal with formatting when you select.

Comment: You have totally reason in this , thanks.

Comment: Is your question about (a) inserting the numbers into the database, or (b) formatting them when you select the, back out of the database?

Comment: Either one of them can be my solution, as long as it has the format 9.999,99, that is, dot form the thousands and comma for the decimals

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried, and what error or other result you got?